# C++ MySQL error in libmysql.dll

Tags: c++, mysql, dll

I've made an app in C++ that uses mysql to connect to a server, but when I send it to my friends to test it, this is what they get:
**libmysql.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.**

It works completely fine on my pc, I even tried sending another libmysql.dll, same error persists. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `libmysql.dll` is either 64-bit and he is using a 32-bit operating system, or it is depending on other DLLs that aren't installed on his system.

There is a tool called [`dependency walker`](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) that will help you track down that kind of problem, but it is designed for advanced users and in short you should probably install the mysql client *using a mysql installer* instead.

Comment: well due to other problems I had to install 32 bit MySQL libs and his pc is 32 bit.

So he'd have to install mysql too for it to work?

Comment: To get just the client libraries, he won't have to install the whole server, just Connector/C (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-c.html) which should solve all dependencies. Download at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: that fixed part of it...
**Host < his internet provider hostname> is not allowed to connect to thes MySQL server.**
How can I fix that?

Comment: @user1126068 That's an unrelated problem regarding database permissions and/or configuration. You may want to write up a new question with more detail how things are configured.